# NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonStreamContext

Tags: java, spring, jackson, updates, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to bump the jackson version number from 2.8.6 to 2.9.8 and it is just not working the way it is supposed to work.

It's giving this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonStreamContext.<init>(II)V

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBufferReadContext.<init>(TokenBufferReadContext.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBufferReadContext.createRootContext(TokenBufferReadContext.java:89)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer$Parser.<init>(TokenBuffer.java:1298)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer.asParser(TokenBuffer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer.asParser(TokenBuffer.java:242)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.valueToTree(ObjectMapper.java:2798)
    at com.example.FooTest.testFilter(FooTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: are you upgrading both `jackson-databind` and `jackson-core`?

Comment: Yes, I am upgrading both.

Comment: uhm, are you using maven? if so, can you use `mvn dependency:tree` and check that the versions are not overridden?

Comment: Yup, I am using maven. Just ran that command in the project directory and got a BUILD SUCCESS.

Comment: ok, but the build can succeed and still give the nosuchmethoderror at runtime- can you post the output of "mvn dependency:tree"?

Comment: I can but I don't think I should because that would basically mean giving out the project directory. Can you tell me what you would have checked had I posted it here?

Comment: u should check the resolved version for jackson databind and jackson core- if they are both 2.9.8

Comment: The project has multiple dependencies (obviously) and one of the dependency needs a sub-dependency of jackson-core version 2.8.7. Does that make a difference?
Also, the project uses javaslang-jackson too. Can that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is almost surely the problem; you should make sure version 2.8.9 is being used.

Comment: @Raj what exact dependency has sub-dependency on jackson-core 2.8.7?

Comment: Sentry version 1.7.16

Comment: @Raj Look at my answer

Comment: @amseager I tried to do what you suggested. Didn't work. The main problem is in the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.valueToTree method. I think they have updated the method which is messing up some stuff.

Comment: I'm going to file a Github issue for this.

Comment: Yeah, that could be too :( Good luck with an issue.

Comment: @Raj, what the web server do you use? Do you have a `Unit test` which serialises/deserialises some objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to exclude all "stale" transient dependencies.

F.e., as you said, you have Sentry 1.7.16 which depends on the old version of jackson-core (2.8.7). So, in your pom.xml you have smth like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
        <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now replace it with :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
        <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.16</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

It will exclude that transient dependency on the old jackson-core. Note that you don't need to specify the version in the exclusion block.

Do the same with other conflicting libraries if needed.